# How does the Event-API of "Spigot / Bukkit" work?

Tags: java, api, events, listener, bukkit

Iam trying to understand, how object-oriented programming in Java works. Herefor I thougth the Spigot-API would be a very nice example.

For everyone, who doesnt know spigot : Its an API for making minecraft plugins.

I reached the point, where I understood quite a few things, but now I´m stuck on "Eventlistener". There is an Event-API in Spigot for this : https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/using-the-event-api/

This page explains how to use listeners. But how is it possible, to implement an whole Interface without all methods and **not** to use the *@Override* annotation ?

Comment: Are you referring to how you create a custom event?

Comment: Please, be more specific in your question. Give us examples of code.

Comment: Not direct. I know how to create an event, because its only a own class. But i want to know, how to make a custom Interface (which is used to implement for a listener class)  And as I told, how to NOT use all different methods as in Spigot. (Everyhing is on the page, where i send the link)

Comment: @EugeneMamaev There is no specific code. Everything is on the page, where i send the link. Its a normal question without any code because I try to understand it, before I write any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interface to tag all listeners.

It doesn't contain any methods so there is nothing to override.